# Pulsating (cold) tap water

Tags: water, water-pressure

When not running any warm water, and having my tap about half open, the cold water pulsates a bit. The stream moves forwards and backwards about half a centimeter. I'm assuming the pressure fluctuates.

When showering (thermostatic tap) I also hear that the water pressure fluctuates.

What could cause this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a wide variety of reasons why this happens ranging from the water meter to air in the lines and water hammer. The easiest way to fix it is to install a cushion tank or expansion tank you have to make sure it's a potable water vision.

**Here's an example of one**[image]www.amazon.ca

They are relatively inexpensive but do require some plumbing to install.